# How can I namespace routes only in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can add name spacing to explicit routes that begin with get, patch, put, post and not have to namespace models or controllers, I would just have to prepend the namespace to the paths in my views but how can I do the same for declared resources without having to edit my models and controllers?

Comment: I guess you would have to use a scope block. From the docs (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing):

If instead you want to route /admin/articles to ArticlesController (without the Admin:: module prefix), you can specify the path with a scope block:

scope '/admin' do
  resources :articles, :comments
end

Comment: @Smek this is *the* answer, so you could always post it as such.

Comment: @engineersmnky, sure I just did.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use a scope block to achieve this. From the docs (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing):

If instead you want to route /admin/articles to ArticlesController (without the Admin:: module prefix), you can specify the path with a scope block:

```rb
scope '/admin' do
  resources :articles, :comments
end
```